# Rotate image to angle on click with Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I am creating a speedometer with with kineticjs and I need the ability to rotate the needle it to a specified angle when the user clicks a button. I also need to be able to set the rotation point as well since it is not in the center.

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and kinetic 1.5.1

Here is what I have so far:

```
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'needle',
        width: 152,
        height: 152
      });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var needle = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 63,
          y: 65,
          image: imageObj,
          width: 83,
          height: 22
        });

        // add the shape to the layer
        layer.add(needle);

        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(layer);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://example.com/assets/img/layout/dials/speedo_needle.png'); ?>';
```

So taking this example how would I rotate the needle to whatever angle I want in an interval or click event?

Answer (score 1):

To rotate the image, use a function with `imageObject.setRotation(45)` where '45' is number of degrees.

To define the rotation point, set offset propertie for imageObject, or change it dynamically with imageObject.setOffsetX(100) and imageObject.setOffsetY(100) or any other number.

Comment: I tried this and got a javascript error imageObj.setRotation() is not a function. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Then, try setRotationDeg() instead